# Knockout css bindings within a foreach

Tags: css, knockout.js

I'm trying to do some templating for the site I'm working on the make it more reusable. To do this I'm using knockout to help with data-binding to transfer info from a json fine.

However, I'm having quite a bit of trouble passing a css property object to a span element within my template.

My html template kind of looks like this

```
<div data-bind="cssProperties: properties, css: { hidden : EvalDisplay() == false }">
    <p>
    <!-- ko foreach: options -->
        <label class="btn">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        **<span class='optionText' data-bind="cssProperties: $parent.properties, html: Value"></span>** 
        </label>&nbsp;
    <!-- /ko -->
    </p>
</div>
```

The span with the asterisks next to it is what's giving me trouble. If I move that outside of the foreach loop then it works fine and the property is added, but if I keep it inside that loop where I need it to be it's just not being applies.

Any help would be great. I am very new at knockout so I don't know all the cool little tricks yet.

And before you ask, yes the css property has to be in the json and not in a css sheet. It needs to be where non-technical people can access it to change it.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: I don't believe I can put json in a fiddle and I'm unsure how to include knockout.

Comment: You could include example data of what the json would like and could include knockout in the external resources or select it from the frameworks dropdown

Comment: Have you tried the knockout context debugger? you can use it to inspect the element and see the knockout binding context for it https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof?hl=en Presumably the cssProperties is a custom binding you have created? and you probably need to change `$parent.properties` to `$root.properties`

Comment: @avaholic Honestly the json file is huge...it's over 30,000 lines and would take quite a bit of time (time I really don't have) to get something out of it that is not confidential company data.

Comment: @Pricey, I actually downloaded that, but had to delete it because it kept crashing my browser. There is too much knockout going on one the page. It's a huge single page app.

Comment: @zazvorniki were you using the debugging part of it? ive used it with some pretty big KO viewmodels just for the inspector part and never had that problem, it adds a new tab to the web developer toolbar that shows you the binding context.. the debugging part of the tool does get too much so i just dont enable it.

Comment: @Pricey, I was using the debugging part of it. My company computer is old (and only has 4gig memory) and I can hardly run chrome without it crashing ever twenty minutes or so.

Comment: @zazvorniki the reason i mentioned it was because of you saying that moving the `span` outside of the foreach fixes your issue, thats usually down to the binding context i.e. `$parent` not being what you expect. This post might be useful http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/06/knockout-debugging-strategies-plugin.html

Comment: What's in your `cssProperties` binding? I've made this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cpu1361f/, seems to work ok.

Comment: Here, I've updated it, now it actually adds some css classes: http://jsfiddle.net/cpu1361f/1/